# Можно ли вращать приложения в Windows?

Tags: c#

Можно ли вращать из своего приложения , другие запущенные приложения в Windows ?

Либо просто переворачивать.

- Язык программирования: C#
- Платформа: WPF
- Операционная система: Windows 10 x64

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

На сколько мне подсказал гугл, то:

- окна внешних программ нельзя
- WPF можно через rotation transforms
- WinForms ВОЗМОЖНО(не уверен) можно через добавление референса на `Microsoft.WindowsCE.Forms` , а так же на старте программы всунуть в мейн **ДО ТОГО КАК ФОРМА БУДЕТ ЗАГРУЖЕНА** `SystemSettings.ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Angle180;`

Это хоть и не полный ответ, но, уверен, теперь ты знаешь куда копать. :)

Comment: *WPF можно через rotation transforms* — заголовок окна, рамку и прочее разве вращает?

Comment: @АндрейNOP понятия не имею. Но если что, заголовок окна и рамку можно кастомными сделать.